# Java 8 Streams API HAVING clause equivalent in a GroupingBy?

Tags: java, java-8, stream

I have run into a hard to solve problem in `Streams API`. Well, it is solvable but not elegantly within a single call from what I can tell. Below, taking a stream of `FeatureContentWeight` objects, I want to group by **feature** and **content** and obtain **maximum weights** per Feature and Content. I get the values from the `Map` at the very end since I have no need for maintaining a `Map`. The problem is, I only **want groups that have more than 3 items** in them. So I want the maximum weights per feature and content for **Feature,Content pairs** that have exceeded a given count. In `SQL` this would just be a simple `HAVING` clause. In `Streams API` it doesn't look trivial but I have only been at `Streams API` for a few days now.

Any ideas appreciated. Below is my approach,

```
List<FeatureContentWeight> nearestNeighbors = neighborPostings
    .stream()
    .collect(
    groupingBy(
        p -> FeatureContent.Create(p.getFeatureId(), p.getContentId()), 
        collectingAndThen(maxBy(comparingDouble(FeatureContentWeight::getWeight)),Optional::get))).values();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description, it seems that you want to filter the map which is the result of grouping. So you could apply a `toMap` collector on the result of grouping and then filter its `values()` in order to only keep those which have a length of 3 or more. You could probably also skip the map creation and use `partitioningBy` collector, but this may be more awkward.

Finally, for transforming maps, I find that Guava's helper functions such as [`Maps.filterValues()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#filterValues%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) sometimes offer shorter and more readable syntax than Java 8 (streams syntax is nice for lists but for maps it sometimes gets terrible). You can use closures with Guava if you're on Java 8, so you could write something like:

```
Map<A,B> unfiltered = <Java 8 grouping>
return Maps.filterValues(unfiltered, list -> list.size() > 3);
```

Comment: This is nice comment. I agree that partitionBy sounds like a good option for satisfying conditions. It is also nice to see someone agrees that working with maps can be a bit frustrating in the Streams API. I find myself getting the entry set or the values often and then converting to a stream etc.. It gets verbose. At the same time, I'm liking Streams API more than C# Linq which is completely opaque.

Comment: @TheOldHag I don't know C# but I find Scala's syntax for functional transformations quite nice, both for lists and maps. It's less verbose than in Java 8 because it was designed into the language right from the start and not added later on and so there were no issues related to preserving backward compatibility in the language.

Answer (score 4):

As you've noticed, unfortunately, there is no streaming `GROUP BY` operation in the JDK's `Stream` API (even if there's a streaming `distinct()` operation). `collect()` is a terminal operation that collects groups and aggregations into a concrete `Map`.

However, as explained in this [article showing SQL clauses and their equivalents in Java 8 Streams](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/08/13/common-sql-clauses-and-their-equivalents-in-java-8-streams/), you can re-stream the `Map.entrySet()` and perform further operations on that.

Applied to your code (I'm making some assumptions here):

```
Map<FeatureContentWeight, Double> nearestNeighbors = neighborPostings
    .stream()

    // GROUP BY featureId, contentId
    .collect(
        groupingBy(
            p -> FeatureContent.Create(p.getFeatureId(), p.getContentId())
        )
    )

    // HAVING count(*) >= 3
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().size() >= 3)

    // SELECT grp, MAX(weight)
    .map(e -> e.getValue().stream().collect(
        maxBy(comparingDouble(w -> w.getWeight))
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resultMap.values().removeIf(lst -> lst.size() < 3)
```

just remove everything you do not need from the result

Comment: Could you elaborate? And make format coding eg with 3x`